How to go from $O(k^{2k}(2k+1)^k)$ to $O(2^{4k\log k})$?
How does one go from $O(k^{2k}(2k+1)^k)$ to $O(2^{4k\log k})$?
Does it go something along the lines of:
$$
k^{2k}(2k+1)^k\\
= (2^{\log k})^{2k} (2^{\log (2k+1)})^k\\
= O(2^{2k\log k} 2^{k(\log k + 2)})\\
= O(2^{2k\log k} 2^{k\log k + 2k})\\
= O(2^{2k\log k} 2^{2k\log k})\\
= O(2^{4k\log k})
$$
?

How you obtain $\log(2k+1)=\log k+2$ from second line to third?

@zkutch I don't, I obtain $\log(2k+1) = O(\log k+2)$, since $\log k + 2 = \log(4k) > \log(2k+1)$

yes what you showed is fine. of course there is an inequality on the line before the last line but that's fine, i.e., $k \log k+ 2k < 2 k \log k$ in the exponent.

Understand. If this will be useful, what you obtained is estimation with $2^{4k\log k}=k^{4k}$, while $k^{2k}(2k+1)^k \sim 2^k k^{3k}$.

@kodlu doesn't the big O notation take care of inequalities anyway? If something is upper bounded by $x$, and $x<y$, then it is also upper bounded by $y$

Increasing the upper bound is not a problem: in Big O you can multiply by any positive function with infinite limit. But by increasing the bound you increase the class of functions and lose the accuracy of the bound. In your case $O(k^{2k}(2k+1)^k)\subset O(2^{4k\log k})$, but $O(2^{4k\log k}) \not\subset O(k^{2k}(2k+1)^k)$

As discussed in the comments, the proposed procedure is correct.
